# EDNS buffer size impact

Tags: domain-name-system

I have seen many recommendation for the buffer size (here for example https://github.com/dns-violations/dnsflagday/issues/125), but I do not understand what would be the impact in choosing one or another one.

How did they come up with those size? Were they from a benchmark or monitoring from real-world cases?

In the RFC6891 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6891#section-6.2.5), it says "A requestor SHOULD choose to use a fallback mechanism that begins with a large size, such as 4096.  If that fails, a fallback around the range of 1280-1410 bytes SHOULD be tried". What is the point with starting with a big size and retry again? it will just slower the resolution.
Is a 4096 buffer size as fast as 1280? in that case, their statement would make sense I guess?

Comment: The idea is to try having an UDP packet that can travel without fragmentation. This hugely depends on the network. Use a too big value and the network won't accept the packet without fragmentation which yields to either problems or at least poor performance. Use a too low value (or none) and then some DNS replies can't fit anymore in the packet and hence the resolver has to try again over TCP (and hence bad performances).

Comment: Also relevant: https://dnsflagday.net/2020/#dns-flag-day-2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [current recommendation as documented for the 2020 DNS flag day](https://dnsflagday.net/2020/#dns-flag-day-2020) for the default EDNS buffer size of 1232 bytes is selected to get the maximum buffer size while avoiding IP fragmentation in essentially any network.

The IPv6 spec mandates a 1280 bytes MTU as the baseline.
Counting backwards from that you have: 1280 (mandated minimum MTU for IPv6) - 48 (length of IP and UDP headers) = 1232 (available payload length).
IPv4 does not mandate a useful minimum MTU value, but in practice the expectations are not lower. For one thing, regular Ethernet has 1500 bytes MTU (various tunneling solutions may take away a little from that).

The reason why you want a large buffer size is to avoid getting a truncated response (`TC` flag), which triggers the client to retry the same query over TCP. Opening a TCP connection is comparatively slow, so it's beneficial in terms of performance when this can be avoided.

Strategies like starting at a larger buffer size and shrinking it "if it didn't work" were there to maximize the benefits of avoiding truncation.

Avoiding IP fragmentation is essentially getting more priority with the explicit recommendation of having a default 1232 buffer size across the board.
The reason why you want to avoid fragmentation is simply that it causes problems. There are reliability concerns (fragments may simply never arrive) as well as security concerns (fragments are more spoofable).

The reason why the original EDNS0 buffer size specification was not as strongly worded regarding avoiding fragmentation (although this was mentioned) and the interpretation of the spec was in many cases not very conservative is, to my understanding, simply because the extent of the negative effects was not as clearly understood at the time.
Running DNS with often quite large buffer sizes (eg 4096 by default) has made these problems evident, though.